# Kronecker delta and Potential at an infinitesimal boundary x0

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

Help with a model please! This is intuitive I am sorry.

Two orthogonal wavefunctions, kinetic with V=0, both ground state, periodically inphase at the intersection, which is a boundary of infinitesimal small size, x0, and has a potential energy V>0 to infinity. This is like two one-dimensional square wells intersecting at the boundary.

A Kronecker delta dij occurs at the boundary, probability density=1 and is an observable- An impulse onto the Real-plane.

This is a symmetry-breaking event, but for it to be periodic, the complex wavefunctions would need to be non-degenerate.

Can it be possible that the potential energy of the boundary itself converts exactly the amount of kinetic energy back to the  complex wavefunctions for them to continue perpetually and allow for periodic impulses?

In other words, the boundary becomes part of the energy of the wavefunction,and is itself an operator. Classically imagining a ball on a slope, that rises under the ball, resulting in kinetic energy exactly matching the potential energy of this operation.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/721457/2451

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Time independent Schr. equationdelta H (psi) = T(psi) x V (boundary)= delta E (psi)